# spring autoconfiguration class is missing in META-INF/spring.factories

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-spark

I'm trying to create spring based application but after the build i'm getting exception while initializing the spring context -> `No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories`.
I'm working heavily with spark in my application and i'm forced to use `maven-assembly-plugin` to package my jar (otherwise i'm unable to run spark job).

sample of my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyMainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyMainClass.class).web(false)
                                                                                                   .run(args);
        SparkJob job = ctx.getBean(SparkJob.class);
        job.prepareJobAndRun();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

when i add

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
org.mypackage.MyMainClass
```

everything works as expected, but i don't want to add them manually.
Any chance to make this work without the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to found out, that you can add your own `META-INF/spring.factories` to `src/main/resources`. This custom spring.factories will be then packed to jar. Tested, working.