# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner not working after packaging in Jar but works in IDE

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4

I am packaging JUnit test cases and suites in a jar and trying to execute these using JUnit core from inside main. The issue is that when I execute these testcases after packaging in JAR, beans are not injected (which implies an issue with spring context.) However, when I execute main method from IDE, beans are injected and everything works.

These test cases have a parent class which is loading the spring context.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class } )
public abstract class BaseTest {

    @Autowired
    protected WebDriver driver;

    @PreDestroy
    public void teardown() {
        ...
    }
}
```

A test class and suite-

```
public class SomeTestClass extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void someTestCase() {
        ...
    }
}


@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    SomeTestClass.class
})
public class SomeTestSuite { }
```

There's a main method which is being used to execute these testcases/suites with JUnitCore.

```
    public static void main(String...args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(SomeTestSuite.class);

        if (result.wasSuccessful()) {
            LOGGER.info("All tests executed successfully: {}", result);
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("There are failures");
            for (Failure failure: result.getFailures()) {
                LOGGER.error("failure: {} msg: {} desc: {}", failure, failure.getMessage(), failure.getDescription(), failure.getException());
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting NullPointerException when executing this via JAR but no issues when execute main method from within IDE.
I am using IntelliJ 2017.2.x, JUnit 4.12 for testcases and maven shade plugin 3.0 to package jar.

**EDIT 1**
Executing jar as -

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

NPE when executing via JAR-

```
2017-11-29 10:16:00,567 [TestCasesExecutor:44] ERROR junit.framework.Test  - failure: testMethodName(testClass): null msg: null desc: testMethodName(testClass)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:770)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:96)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:71)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
        at com.mycom.SomeTestClass.setup(BaseTest.java:37)
        at com.mycom.testcases.SplunkGcpScoreCardTest.logoutFromGcpScorecard(SplunkGcpScoreCardTest.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:105)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(JUnitCore.java:62)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(JUnitCore.java:49)
        at com.mycom.TestCasesExecutor.main(TestCasesExecutor.java:37)
```

Background - I have some selenium test cases for an app in production.  It creates an instance of headless chrome for execution. **The reason these were wrapped as test cases is because ideally we wanted to integrate this with saucelabs** (saucelabs needs selenium code wrapped as testcases for execution.) However, currently there are some constraints as to how saucelabs is setup in my organization and we can't go down that road as of today but while we figure this out, we kept writing this code. So now, I am trying to create a JAR with this code and deploy it in production. This way, I don't have to make a lot of changes when we are able to move with Saucelabs.

Comment: I would argue that your unit tests do not belong in any executable JAR.  They should run in your IDE or integrated build tool before being packaged.

Comment: My scenario is different. These are selenium test-cases for a business web app. As much as I would like to integrate these with saucelabs, currently it is not an option.

Comment: Doesn't sound different to me.  Good luck.   The stack trace tells you what is null.  That'll give you a hint.

Comment: Paste your NPE and any other log output you get. Paste how you run this "via JAR". And explain why you even want to run junit tests packaged in main from jar, rather than using maven.

Comment: NPE pasted above and JAR is being triggered as "java -jar myjar.jar". NPE occurs when code uses object of type Environment from spring core. It is supposed to be **Autowired**. I printed class members which were to be Autowired and they are all null.

Comment: Added some background at bottom of my edit to share some perspective. I am open to discussing this design as long as we can make it work with minimal changes when we go down saucelabs route.

Comment: Not sure your problem is Spring related?  Looks like a selenium problem.

Comment: Invokes JAR -> triggers JUnitCore -> triggers JUnitTestcase -> uses SpringJUnit4ClassRunner -> bean injection fails. How is this a selenium problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After troubleshooting through spring code and logs, I figured that it's failing because **my JAR doesn't have `spring.factories` file in it's `META-INF`**. 
Possible solutions-

1. Change project to spring boot, enable auto-configuration and create a JAR using spring boot maven plugin which takes care of packaging it right.
2. Create `spring.factories` file in `src/main/resources/META-INF`. You can write your own ([refer spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html)) or copy `spring.factories` from any spring dependency in your project. [Related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586999/spring-autoconfiguration-class-is-missing-in-meta-inf-spring-factories).

I went with option 2 because it seemed easy in this scenario. I didn't need anything more than just spring.factories from spring-boot dependency, so option 1 would have been an overkill.